# How to solve given expression?

Tags: functions, derivatives

We know that the derivative  $f'(1)=3$.

$$
 \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(1-5h^2)-f(1+3h^2)}{h^2(h+1)}=?
$$

I try to solve it by applying L'Hôpital's rule, but answer was incorrect.

Since $f$ is differentiable at $x=1$, it has Continuity, so its right and left limit at $x=1$ are equal. So the numerator and denominator are zero. I think we can use L'Hôpital's rule.

With given $f'(1)=3$
$$
 \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(1-5h^2)-f(1+3h^2)}{h^2(h+1)}=\frac {0}{0},
$$

$$
 \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-10hf(1-5h^2)-6hf(1+3h^2)}{3h^2+1}=\frac {-16 h f'(1)}{3 h ^ 2 +1}=\frac {0}{1}=0,
$$
$$
{h \to 0} \implies f'(1-5h^2)=f'(1+3h^2).
$$

What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: Do you know Taylor series ? If yes, did you try ?

Comment: know I dont know. I just use hopital, but my answer was zero.

Comment: L'Hopital only applies if the limit is of the form $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$, otherwise it is not valid. Since we don't know anything about $f$, you can't blindly apply L'Hopital without more information.

Comment: @Andrew  Isn't the limit 0/0 right now?

Comment: Please do type it out, don't put the picture instead of equations.

Comment: No it's not! See [this FAQ entry](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for help.

Comment: @Ruslan i edited :) But it was difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$E=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(1-5h^2)-f(1+3h^2)}{h^3+h^2}$$ $$E=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{[f(1-5h^2)-f(1)]-[f(1+3h^2)-f(1)]}{h^3+h^2}$$ $$E=\Big(\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(1-5h^2)-f(1)}{5h^2}.\dfrac{5h^2}{h^3+h^2}\Big)-\Big(\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(1+3h^2)-f(1)}{3h^2}.\dfrac{3h^2}{h^3+h^2}\Big)$$ $$E=-5f'(1)-3f'(1)$$

Comment: The $+$ in the middle should be a $-$, I guess. Fix the typo and the result. Nice answer ! Cheers.

Comment: I add my answer

Comment: @user123: Your mistake is $$-10hf'(1-5h^2)-6hf'(1+3h^2)=-16hf'(1).$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(1+3h^2)- f(1-5h^2)}{8h^2}= f'(1)$$

Can you substitute this inside?

Comment: where dose 8h^2 come from?

Comment: That is the difference between $-5h^2$ and $3h^2$. You can do it in 2 steps as suggested by Nilan. Although the sign there is currently wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the third line of your notes, the denominator is supposed to be the derivative of $h^2(h+1)$; this is $3h^2+2h$ and not $3h^2+1$ as you wrote. If you fix this, you get the result.

Comment: oh, thanks. I made a mistake.

Comment: If I had received a dollar for each of my mistakes, I should be a billionaire !!

Comment: @OK :) I solve it many times but didn't notice that mistake :)